# How can i write unit test for Gridview_RowCommand event?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, gridview

I think question is itself explanatory. I am wondering how it is possible to write NUnit tests for such events. If you go deeper, it looks like using ASP.NET is not appropriate for writing unit tests.

Thoughts please ..

**Edit**
The idea of this question is, if you have a grid view in your page and let's say you have gridview.rowcommand event subscribed on this control. And, you have some logic that is implemented based on the rowcommand event arguments. Now, how will you test this method using a unit testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to test? Do you want to test the logic inside `GridView.RowCommand`, or something else?

You can do this; wrap any logic inside the `GridView.RowCommand` inside a method, and test that method instead of the event.

If you absolutely positively must test the ASP.Net event, then you may need [Ivonna](http://sm-art.biz/Ivonna.aspx), a Typemock add-on. But I have to warn you that it's not free